# assign array values to drop down in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this:

```
[
  [{
    "station_territory": "Peshawar-CMD"
  }, {
    "station_territory": "Faisalabad-CMD"
  }],
  [{
    "station_territory": "Faisalabad-FEM"
  }]
];
```

How can I assign it to a multiple drop down where the `id` is the station? I tried this code:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  $("#station") = value;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create `option` elements within the `select` you can loop through each level of the arrays in `data` create the `option` elements which you can assign to the `select`.

Note that in jQuery you never assign anything to a jQuery object itself; you use the methods that jQuery provides in order to amend elements. In this case you can use `append()`:

```js
var data = [
  [{
    "station_territory": "Peshawar-CMD"
  }, {
    "station_territory": "Faisalabad-CMD"
  }],
  [{
    "station_territory": "Faisalabad-FEM"
  }]
];

var options = [];
data.forEach(function(outer) {
  outer.forEach(function(inner) {
    options.push(`<option value="${inner.station_territory}">${inner.station_territory}</option>`);
  });
});
$("#station").append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="station"></select>
```

Comment: an error generate , can u plz resolve it
`index.php?action=edit_employee&empID=5309:4393 Uncaught TypeError: data[0].map is not a function

Comment: Possibly try `data = JSON.parse(data)` first.

Comment: now its working but if the response is 
`
[[{"station_territory":"City0"},{"station_territory":"City1"}],[{"station_territory":"City2"}]]
`
its showing only  1st two values not 3rd

Comment: That's because it's a completely different data structure. You now have multiple arrays at different levels.

Comment: i just want  to dynamically append values from json array to multiple based drop down

Comment: I updated the answer for you, but please give accurate information in your future questions.